# Django Admin changeform_view methosdont' permit open edit data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

In my django project i whant add a table with last data insert above any add/edit form, so in my admin.py i write:

```
class t_proj_routeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):        
    def changeform_view(self, request, obj_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        l_mod = t_proj_route.objects.latest('id')

        extra_context = {
            'lmod': l_mod,
        }
        return super(t_proj_routeAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

then in my template use the data for add a table.
All done if i open an ADD page,, but whe i try to modify an already present record django redirect me ever on a new ADD, and i am unable to open edit page with data selected.

How can i use this technique for manage ADD and EDIT record?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i suggest to define methods like this one:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, obj_id, form_url, extra_context=None):
```

this method was called every time edit and add actions was called, if you force obj_id and form_url variables to blank, when try to edit your data the method return a new blank form, that is the ADD template.

In return statement use the complete methods variables insertion:

```
return super(t_proj_routeAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, obj_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

It should work

Bye